# A group $G$ of order $p^n$ is cyclic iff it is abelian having a unique subgroup of order $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

> **Theorem:** A group $G$ of order $p^n$ is cyclic iff it is abelian having a unique subgroup of order $p$.

My problem is with the converse. If $a\in G$ have the largest order, say $p^k$, and $⟨a⟩$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then there is $x\in G$ with $x\notin ⟨a⟩$ but with $x^p\in ⟨a⟩$.

I understand we must have an element of $G$ not in $⟨a⟩$ given that it's a proper subgroup. But I don't know why we must have such a $x$ so that $x^p$ is in $⟨a⟩$.

What I know is that $⟨G\setminus ⟨a⟩⟩ = G$, but don't know how this implies that we should have $x^p\in ⟨a⟩$ for a certain $x\notin ⟨a⟩$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a smallest positive exponent $\ell$ such that $x^\ell\in \langle a\rangle$. Do you see why $\ell$ must be a power of $p$? Do you see why replacing $x$ with its suitable power leads to the conclusion?

Comment: Have you learned about quotient groups? Knowing that will affect the most efficient answer, so I/we need to ask :-)

Comment: I haven't learned about it yet. I don't see why $l$ must be like that, could you please explain further?

Comment: The order of $x$, call it $m$, is a power of $p$ by Lagrange. And $\ell$ must be a factor of $m$ for the set of integers $k$ such that $x^k\in\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{Z}$, hence generated by its smallest positive element.